# XML Serialization not including inherited or overridden properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, properties, abstract-class

I have a class structure with inheritance and a constructor based on another set of classes with inheritance. I'd draw up a simple version but I feel having the whole will make understanding a lot easier so here is the classes and their inheritance.

In the file `Tag.cs`

```
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(IntTag)),
    XmlInclude(typeof(IntTagConfiguration))]
[Serializable]
public abstract class Tag
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string Description { get; }
    public abstract AccessTypeEnum Access { get; }
    public abstract DataTypeEnum Type { get; }
    public abstract bool Alarmed { get; }
    public abstract AcquisitionTypeEnum AcquisitionType { get; }
    public abstract DateTime AcquisitionDate { get; set; }
    public abstract int AcquisitionRate { get; }
    public abstract string Address { get; }
    public abstract bool AuditTrail { get; }
    public abstract bool Historisation { get; }
    public abstract HistorisationTypeEnum HistorisationType { get; }
    public abstract int HistorisationRate { get; }
    public abstract bool Forceable { get; }
    public abstract bool ForceValue { get; }

    public Tag() { }
}

[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
[Serializable]
public class IntTag : Tag
{
    public override string Name { get; }
    public override string Description { get; }
    public override AccessTypeEnum Access { get; }
    public override DataTypeEnum Type { get; }
    public override bool Alarmed { get; }
    public override AcquisitionTypeEnum AcquisitionType { get; }
    public override DateTime AcquisitionDate { get; set; }
    public override int AcquisitionRate { get; }
    public override string Address { get; }
    public override bool AuditTrail { get; }
    public override bool Historisation { get; }
    public override HistorisationTypeEnum HistorisationType { get; }
    public override int HistorisationRate { get; }
    public override bool Forceable { get; } // CAN the value for this tag be forced
    public override bool ForceValue { get; } // IS the value for this tag forced
    public int InitialValue { get; }
    public int MinimumValue { get; }
    public int MaximumValue { get; }
    public int ForcedValue { get; }
    public string Unit { get; }
    private int _currentValue;
    public int CurrentValue 
    { 
        get => _currentValue;
        set 
        {
            _currentValue = value;
            OnCurrentValueUpdated(this); // Event method, not related to serialization issue
        }
    }

    public IntTag(IntTagConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Name = configuration.Name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration.Name));
        Description = configuration.Description ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration.Description));
        Access = configuration.Access;
        Type = configuration.Type;
        Alarmed = configuration.Alarmed;
        AcquisitionType = configuration.AcquisitionType;
        AcquisitionRate = configuration.AcquisitionRate;
        Address = configuration.Address ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration.Address));
        AuditTrail = configuration.AuditTrail;
        Historisation = configuration.Historisation;
        HistorisationType = configuration.HistorisationType;
        HistorisationRate = configuration.HistorisationRate;
        Forceable = configuration.Forceable;
        ForceValue = configuration.ForceValue;
        InitialValue = configuration.InitialValue;
        MinimumValue = configuration.MinimumValue;
        MaximumValue = configuration.MaximumValue;
        ForcedValue = configuration.ForcedValue;
        Unit = configuration.Unit ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration.Unit));
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IntTag() { }
}
```

In the file `TagConfiguration.cs`

```
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(IntTag)),
    XmlInclude(typeof(IntTagConfiguration))]
[Serializable]
public class TagConfiguration
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
    public AccessTypeEnum Access { get; }
    public DataTypeEnum Type { get; }
    public bool Alarmed { get; }
    public AcquisitionTypeEnum AcquisitionType { get; }
    public int AcquisitionRate { get; }
    public string Address { get; }
    public bool AuditTrail { get; }
    public bool Historisation { get; }
    public HistorisationTypeEnum HistorisationType { get; }
    public int HistorisationRate { get; }
    public bool Forceable { get; } // CAN the value for this tag be forced
    public bool ForceValue { get; } // IS the value for this tag forced

    public TagConfiguration(string name, string description, AccessTypeEnum access, DataTypeEnum type, bool alarmed, AcquisitionTypeEnum acquisitionType, int acquisitionRate, string address, bool auditTrail, bool historisation, HistorisationTypeEnum historisationType, int historisationRate, bool forceable, bool forceValue)
    {
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        Description = description ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(description));
        Access = access;
        Type = type;
        Alarmed = alarmed;
        AcquisitionType = acquisitionType;
        AcquisitionRate = acquisitionRate;
        Address = address ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));
        AuditTrail = auditTrail;
        Historisation = historisation;
        HistorisationType = historisationType;
        HistorisationRate = historisationRate;
        Forceable = forceable;
        ForceValue = forceValue;
    }

    public TagConfiguration() { }
}

[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
[Serializable]
public class IntTagConfiguration : TagConfiguration
{
    public int InitialValue { get; }
    public int MinimumValue { get; }
    public int MaximumValue { get; }
    public int ForcedValue { get; }
    public string Unit { get; }

    public IntTagConfiguration(int initialValue, int minimumValue, int maximumValue, int forcedValue, string unit, string name, string description, AccessTypeEnum access, DataTypeEnum type, bool alarmed, AcquisitionTypeEnum acquisitionType, int acquisitionRate, string address, bool auditTrail, bool historisation, HistorisationTypeEnum historisationType, int historisationRate, bool forceable, bool forceValue) : base(name, description, access, type, alarmed, acquisitionType, acquisitionRate, address, auditTrail, historisation, historisationType, historisationRate, forceable, forceValue)
    {
        InitialValue = initialValue;
        MinimumValue = minimumValue;
        MaximumValue = maximumValue;
        ForcedValue = forcedValue;
        Unit = unit ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unit));
    }

    public IntTagConfiguration() { }
}
```

As you can see, there is a TagConfiguration class which I instantiate (hopefully not manually) and create a Tag object from it.

I included the XmlInlcude, Serializable and SettingSerializeAs attributes as necessary and to export the Tags as a list, I run the following code (Note that I have instantiated a IntTagConfiguration object beforehand)

```
List<Tag> tagList = new List<Tag>() { intTag, intTag, intTag, intTag, intTag };

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Tag>));
using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\newTagList.xml"))
{
    xs.Serialize(tw, tagList);
}
```

Resulting from this, I get the following XML file which looks nothing like I expect nor need, it's missing 95% of the properties...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfTag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Tag xsi:type="IntTag">
    <AcquisitionDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</AcquisitionDate>
    <CurrentValue>0</CurrentValue>
  </Tag>
  <Tag xsi:type="IntTag">
    <AcquisitionDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</AcquisitionDate>
    <CurrentValue>0</CurrentValue>
  </Tag>
  <Tag xsi:type="IntTag">
    <AcquisitionDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</AcquisitionDate>
    <CurrentValue>0</CurrentValue>
  </Tag>
  <Tag xsi:type="IntTag">
    <AcquisitionDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</AcquisitionDate>
    <CurrentValue>0</CurrentValue>
  </Tag>
  <Tag xsi:type="IntTag">
    <AcquisitionDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</AcquisitionDate>
    <CurrentValue>0</CurrentValue>
  </Tag>
</ArrayOfTag>
```

I feel the solution is simple but I can't seem to find it.

**What I've tried**

- Adding the `[XmlElement()]` which didn't work
- Adding every `[XmlInclude(...)]` to every class which didn't work

I'm looking, if it wasn't clear, to have an Xml file for a Tag which includes **ALL** of its properties.

Comment: Are you adding data to the classes?  Looks like only the properties that have values are being serialized.

Comment: Classes are initialized using a TagConfiguration instance and then, as configuration implies, they're configured and don't change

Comment: If a property is null the children (values) will not be included in the xml output.  The date AcquisitionDate is being setup to the default date 1/1/1.  The value CurrentValue is set because you have a interface for the value.  Everything else is the default value and not showing in the xml file.